# How to use Items Load Path in dropdown list of AEM Form

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

While creating a dropdown list in my form I noticed a field called "Items Load Path". Can this field be used to provide a url from which it loads the options available in a dropdown list?

Where would the URL reside, and how can I put values in that URL? Can someone please show an example?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its well explained in documentation : http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/developing-forms.html

Create a sling:folder and add the multi-value property on it as shown :
[image]

And add the path in Items Load Path as : /etc/designs/geometrixx/formlistvalues/myList

It will populate values for that drop-down.

Hope this will help.